# SymPy: How to get values from expression

Tags: python, pattern-matching, substitution, sympy

I am trying to write a simple SymPy function.

```
a = Wild('a')
b = Wild('b')
p = Wild('p')
q = Wild('q')
...

if (U).match(b/(a+s)):
    return b*exp(-a*t)
```

Lets say that `U = 3/(7+s)`. I would like my result to be `3*exp(-7*t)`, but it just returns `b*exp(-a*t)`.

Is there a way to get those values and assign them to a and b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  First, set up the system:

```
>>> from sympy import var, Wild, exp
>>> s = var("s")
>>> t = var("t")
>>> a = Wild("a")
>>> b = Wild("b")
>>> U = 3/(7+s)
```

The `.match` method returns a dictionary:

```
>>> U.match(b/(a+s))
{b_: 3, a_: 7}
>>> m = U.match(b/(a+s))
```

which can then be passed as an argument to `.subs`:

```
>>> target = b*exp(-a*t)
>>> target
b_*exp(-t*a_)
>>> target.subs(m)
3*exp(-7*t)
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a side question - why is live.sympy.org often displaying Error: Time limit exceeded? For example, I just added m = U.match(b/(a+s)) in my code between those if and return lines.

Comment: I have no idea; up until a few minutes ago I'm not sure I'd ever heard of live.sympy.org.  It worked for me when I tried it there, FWIW.

Comment: Probably their problem... Thanks for the answer.